# Get table schema using eloquent, get Array to string conversion error

Tags: php, eloquent

i'm trying to get a list of the column data types for a certain table. I have noticed eloquent has some methods that do this so i'm trying to use these.

```
$grammar = DB::connection()->getSchemaBuilder();
$schema = DB::select($grammar->getColumnListing('vehicles'));
```

However i'm getting the following error when calling `getColumnListing`:

> Array to string conversion

Not too sure where this so called `Array` is... the method expects a `String`:

**vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder.php**

```
/**
     * Get the column listing for a given table.
     *
     * @param  string  $table
     * @return array
     */
    public function getColumnListing($table)
    {
        $table = $this->connection->getTablePrefix().$table;

        $results = $this->connection->select($this->grammar->compileColumnListing($table));

        return $this->connection->getPostProcessor()->processColumnListing($results);
    }
```

Comment: `getColumnListing()` returns an array of columns that you are passing to `DB::select()` which expects a string.

Comment: It's much simpler: `Schema::getColumnListing('vehicles');`

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir is there a way to make this return the data type too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel only provides a list of column names:

```
Schema::getColumnListing('vehicles');
```

You can get more details by installing the [`doctrine/dbal`](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal) package:

```
Schema::getConnection()->getDoctrineSchemaManager()->listTableColumns('vehicles');
```